# Apache starting site with xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I recently installed Xampp on my server so I could test out Apache/MySQL/Tomcat. Upon first opening the site, I want the users to go to a login page -- then go to the 'home' page.

I have the login page set up in a separate folder and it works great but I have to open it manually by typing the address in the browser. I have a link on the login page that allows the user to go to the 'home' page (after credentials are verified).

How do I tell Apache to go to this different login page the first time only? Right now it only goes to the 'home' page and I can't figure out how to tell it to go anywhere different.

Any help?

Comment: This is probably something you want to control at the application level (i.e. login verification and redirection if not logged in), not at the Apache level.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I have `site` and I have `site/project`. Right now it's dropping me at `site` and I want it to put me at `site/project`. How do I tell that to Apache?

Comment: It sounded like you wanted to wanted to go to a login page the first time only that a user comes to the site (I assumed because they weren't logged in). Thus my statement was that you should not rely on Apache to enforce login behavior. On your main page, you need to check to see if the user is logged in, and if not, redirect them to the login page. The application (I assume in PHP) would likely utilize a `header()` call to do this.